# Is it possible for "using" keyword to inherit fewer functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, using

In `Derived` there is a `template foo(T)`. There are 2 overloads of `foo()` in `Base`.

```
struct Base
{
  void foo (int x) {}
  void foo (double x) {}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  template<typename T> void foo (T x) {}
  using Base::foo;
};
```

Now, when `foo()` is called with `Derived` object; I want to use only `Base::foo(int)` if applicable, otherwise it should invoke `Derived::foo(T)`.

```
Derived obj;
obj.foo(4);  // calls B::foo(int)
obj.foo(4.5); // calls B::foo(double) <-- can we call Derived::foo(T) ?
```

In short, I want an effect of:

```
using Base::foo(int);
```

Is it possible ? Above is just an example.

Comment: For your consideration: Should all these functions really have the same name?

Comment: @Chris, yes. For `Base` objects, `foo()` is passed `int`/`double`. For `Derived` objects `foo()` is passed any type but it has different computation for `foo(double)`. This is just an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`using` bringes all overloads into the scope. Just hide it in the derived class, it's a bit more to write but does the job:

```
struct Derived : Base
{
  template<typename T> void foo (T x) {}
  void foo(int x){
    Base::foo(x);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a neat way to do this if you want to keep with the template approach is to specialise your template for ints:

```
template<> void Derived::foo<int> (int x) { Base::foo(x) };
```

Everything will be brought in with `using` so I would avoid this in your case, but you can create as many specialisations as you need.

The good thing is that they don't litter your class declaration, but this can also bring maintenance problems if your specialisation is not obvious.